# How do I make a screenshot image accessible?

Tags: html, css, accessibility, wai-aria

I'm trying to make my website fully accessible for devices like screen readers. In one page on my site, I have a screenshot of an application showing a lot of text. For reference, here's my image:

[image: Screenshot of text]

On my page, I'm expecting the user to have read/skimmed the text in this image, so I need screen readers to essentially be able to read all the text in this image. However, there's far too much information to fit in the `<img>`'s alt attribute -- I wouldn't be able to preserve the structure of the text as it appears in the screenshot.

I'm willing to transcribe the entire image, of course, but I don't know quite how to format the transcription. Is there some way I can use aria-label or one of the other ARIA attributes on the `<img>` tag, or should I just include the transcription separately in an invisible block? Would it be best to recreate the image in plain text using a `<pre>` tag, or to create it with semantic HTML? Or is there some other approach entirely that I should be taking?

Comment: i wonder... if it is the documentation for some software, should you describe the screenshot or should you describe what a screen reader would say?

Comment: This isn't the documentation for the software itself; I'm just using a screenshot to illustrate a point. In this case, I was describing my process for solving a particular problem, and at one point, I had to search a lot of files for a certain bit of text. To show this in my blog post, I just added a screenshot of the search results in my text editor. Thus, I'm much more interested in the presenting the actual content of the screenshot rather than merely describing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Be aware that you must provide both a short text alternative and a long text alternative**

Your concern is covered within [1.1.1 Non-text Content](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/text-equiv-all.html) of the WCAG:

> Situation B: If a short description can not serve the same purpose and present the same information as the non-text content (e.g., a chart or diagram):
>
> [G95: Providing short text alternatives that provide a brief description of the non-text content](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20161007/G95) using one of the following Short text alternative techniques for Situation B **AND** one of the following Long text alternative techniques for Situation B :

[...]

> Like `longdesc`, descriptive text provided using `aria-describedby` is separate from the short name provided using the `alt` attribute in HTML.

After setting the label (=short description) of the image using the `alt` attribute for instance, you can set its description by using the `aria-describedby` attribute, using the following technique:
[ARIA15: Using aria-describedby to provide descriptions of images](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20161007/ARIA15)

> ```
> <img src="screenshot.jpg"
>    alt="Screenshot of my application"
>    aria-describedby="long-alternative" />
> ```

```
<div id="long-alternative">insert your full text here</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Please see the following technique to meet WCAG 2.0 success criteria 1.3.1 (Info and Relationships) and 3.3.2 (Labels and Instructions):

https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/ARIA1.html

Basically you set aria-describedby attribute on your image, pointing to an element with the corresponding id and the desired information, as in:

```
<img src="image.png" aria-describedby="description" />

<div id="description">
My description.
</div>
```

The div can have `visibility hidden` or `display none` to hide it from users not requiring accessibility assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that you would give the image tag's css a mediatype of screen, and then create a div or something with the text inside, that had a media type of speech.